# nodejs unable to run angular application with new version of nodejs despite having old version install

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, server, angular12

Having old version installed in my machine but i don't have admin rights to install latest nodejs version so i downloaded binary version of nodejs.
Now how can i run my angular application with that version of node.

````
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4MXo.png
````

Comment: Do you have nvm installed?

Comment: how to install??